# Disable 3D touch for iOS application

Tags: ios, 3dtouch

I have an application that present webViews.

This WebViews present links that I want to handle by myself.

Everything is working great using the delegate methods, but I have a problem when the user is using force touch. In that case, the iOS is making the transition to the link via safari without going listening to my delegate.

My question is - How can I remove the force touch from my app?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The way to remove 3d touch from your web view is -

```
yourWebView.allowsLinkPreview = false
```

Answer (score 8):

According this [WebKit post](https://webkit.org/blog/7016/ios-10-link-preview-api-in-wkwebview/), `allowsLinkPreview` is `false` by default on iOS 9 and enabled by default on iOS 10+

> WebKit supports Peek and Pop as an easy way to preview links. Apps
>   built against the iOS 10 SDK will have Peek and Pop link preview
>   enabled by default, but the feature is not new; since iOS 9, WKWebView
>   clients could opt into Peek-based link previews on 3D Touch-capable
>   devices using the allowsLinkPreview property on WKWebView. When the
>   allowsLinkPreview property is set to true, users can gently press on
>   links to peek them, which loads the link in another view over the app
>   and blurs the app in the background.

try setting it to `false`

Comment: thanks for the right property! but the answer is to set it to false

Answer (score 0):

i believe this is what your looking for:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, shouldPreviewElement elementInfo: WKPreviewElementInfo) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

its a delegate method in `WKUIDelegate` which was added in iOS10. This will disable the force touch preview.